# What's the meaning of __new__ in Haxe for Flash?

Tags: flash, haxe

I saw some code (written for Flash) that looks like this:

```
var _array:Array<Int> = untyped __new__(Array, 10);
```

And I find it creates an `Array` and with a `length` of 10.
However, when I try something like:

```
var _array:Array<Int> = untyped __new__(Array, 1, 2);
```

It creates an `Array` which has two elements.
I'm confused by this, what's the real meaning of `__new__`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is Haxe "magic", see [the wiki](http://old.haxe.org/doc/advanced/magic).

The `__new__` is to call the native constructor, in the case of `Array`, it is different from what Haxe exposes ([`Array` in Haxe doc](http://haxe.org/api/array) vs [`Array` in AS3 doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html)).

Basically using `__new__` initializes the `Array` with a length and/or values without manually doing:

```
var array = [];
for(i in 0...len) array.push(0);
```